# React button not reacting to click event

Tags: reactjs

I am not sure why the 'click me' button is not updating state. The syntax looks good as I have no errors. But clicks are non-responsive. I don't think the handler is invoked at all. I am not able to figure this out. Thanks.

```
    class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){ 
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      username: '',
      username2: "",
      buttonValue: "A"
    }; 
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.elements.username.value)
    this.setState({ username: event.target.elements.username.value }); 
  };
  handleChange2 = event => {  
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({ username2: event.target.value });   
  };
  handlechange3 = event => {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.setState({ buttonValue: event.target.value });
  }
  render() { 
    var x=1;
    return (
    <div> 
      <form onSubmit={this.handleChange}>{/* the input value is captured by event.target.elements.username.value by handleChange*/}
        <label htmlFor="username">username</label> 
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"          
        />
        <input type='submit' /> 
      </form>
      <label>username2</label> 
      <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange2} /> {/* the input value is captured by event.target.value by handlechange2 */}
      <br />
      <button onClick={this.handleChange3}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <h3>Your username value is: {this.state.username}</h3> 
      <h3>Your username2 value is: {this.state.username2}</h3> 
      <h3>Your button value is: {this.state.buttonValue}</h3>
    </div>
      ); 
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click me button is not working because there is spelling typo error in the handler function definition name.

```
handleChange3 = event => { // change handlechange3 to handleChange3
    console.log('clicked');
    this.setState({ buttonValue: event.target.value });
}
```

Comment: The button also does not have `value` property.

Comment: Yes Brain, You are right. I went with answering the core question of not reacting to click event

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought it might be helpful to the OP for when they fix the main problem and then still don't see what they expect in state.

Comment: Fixing that lowercase fixed the issue - the button state is now updating, the button does have value if it is provided explicitly as an attribute. Thanks for looking in to this.

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic]. [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Answer (score 1):

I found two mistake that you were making:

1. Calling function(handlechange3) with lowercase.(compare with my code you will find).
2. Main reason your **state** is not updating because when you call **event** on button click the event is targeting button, which eventually has no **value** property.(you got your state change in case of form submission because there the **event** is targeting form->element->username->value )

**Here is fixed code**

```
 import React from 'react';

 class LoginForm extends React.Component {

 state = {
    username: '',
    username2: "",
    buttonValue: "A"
};
handleChange = event => {
event.preventDefault();
console.log(event.target.elements.username.value)
this.setState({ username: event.target.elements.username.value }); 
};
handleChange2 = event => {  
console.log(event.target.value)
this.setState({ username2: event.target.value });   
};
handleChange3 = () => {
console.log('clicked');
this.setState({ buttonValue: document.getElementById('Satish').value });
console.log(document.getElementById('Satish').value)
}
render() { 
//var x=1;
return (
<div> 
  <form onSubmit={this.handleChange}>{/* the input value is captured by event.target.elements.username.value by handleChange*/}
    <label htmlFor="username">username</label> 
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type='submit' /> 
  </form>
  <label>username2</label> 
  <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange2} id="Satish" /> {/* the input             value is captured by event.target.value by handlechange2 */}
  <br />
  <button onClick={this.handleChange3}>
    Click me
  </button>
  <h3>Your username value is: {this.state.username}</h3> 
  <h3>Your username2 value is: {this.state.username2}</h3> 
  <h3>Your button value is: {this.state.buttonValue}</h3>
</div>
  ); 
  }
  }
  export default LoginForm;
```

To target input value i explicitly added an id to input value named **satish** to get input value.

Hope i helped you :)

Comment: I agree with your first observation - fixing that lowercase alone fixed the issue - the button state is now updating, the button does have value if it is provided explicitly as an attribute. Thanks for looking in to this.